# Magento issue after migration

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm getting the below error after migrating my website (Magento ver. 1.7.0.2), any idea on how to solve the issue?

Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html') in /home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html') in /home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/ovbc5jb5q80z/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 54

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Object.php file on your website on below path.

[Magento_root]/lib/Varien/autoload.php

[Magento_root]/lib/Varien/object.php

If file exists there, try to change the permission of the file and clear cache.

If not you can copy it from a fresh Magento installation